# How can you get the active users connected to a postgreSQL database via SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, active-users

How can you get the active users connected to a postgreSQL database via SQL? This could be the userid's or number of users.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

(question) Don't you get that info in

> select * from [pg_user](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/user-manag.html#DATABASE-USERS);

or using the view [pg_stat_activity](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/monitoring-stats.html):

```
select * from pg_stat_activity;
```

**Added:**

the view says:

> One row per server process, showing database OID, database name, process ID, user OID, **user name**, current query, query's waiting status, time at which the current query began execution, time at which the process was started, and **client's address and port number**. The columns that report data on the current query are available unless the parameter stats_command_string has been turned off. Furthermore, these columns are only visible if the user examining the view is a superuser or the same as the user owning the process being reported on.

can't you filter and get that information? that will be the current users on the Database, you can use began execution time to get all queries from last 5 minutes for example...

something like that.

Comment: No, that is the list of known users, not the number currently connected.

Comment: how about the Stats collector? (follow the link on the view name)

Comment: @mm2010: pg_stat_activity: active users only.   pg_user: list all users

Comment: Downvoted, answer wanders a bit and provides some information that might mislead future readers, for example, pg_user is not useful for finding the active users connected to a PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 40):

Using balexandre's info:

```
SELECT usesysid, usename FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

Comment: You can add `client_addr` to the above query in order to get client's IP.

Answer (score 12):

OP asked for users connected *to a particular database*:

```
-- Who's currently connected to my_great_database?
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity 
  WHERE datname = 'my_great_database';
```

This gets you [all sorts of juicy info](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) (as others have mentioned) such as

- userid (column `usesysid`)
- username (`usename`)
- client application name (`appname`), if it bothers to set that variable -- `psql` does :-)
- IP address (`client_addr`)
- what state it's in (a couple columns related to state and wait status)
- and everybody's favorite, the current SQL command being run (`query`)