# linux : Finding the postgres idle process originator

Tags: linux, postgresql, ps

Actually ,  I am running four daemon program. It makes postgres connection, and it disconnects once through with the stuffs. But When I am putting ps aux , there are lot of postgres idle process being run in my system.  I just want to know , originator of the each idle postres process.  So, that I could find out which process does not close postgres connection properly.

Thanks in  Advance .

Answer (score 4):

Use following command

```
netstat -ntp
```

It will show the process id and process name of postgres connector creator.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using postgresql 9.0, set the "application name" property when you connect so that you can distinguish which client process each server process is talking to. For example (Perl):

```
$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:application_name=test/$$", undef, undef)
```

This will include the client PID in the application name, which is ugly but effective.

If you are connecting over TCP/IP, then `pg_stat_activity` includes the client port which you can use with `lsof` (or `netstat -p`) to find the client process.

Answer (score 0):

See [How can you get the active users connected to a postgreSQL database via SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464623/how-can-you-get-the-active-users-connected-to-a-postgresql-database-via-sql)

that can get the pid and uid of the connected processes

Comment: I think , table shows me the process id of the postres, not the originator of the postgres process  id.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464623/how-can-you-get-the-active-users-connected-to-a-postgresql-database-via-sql/464629#464629 seems to say what your asking for