# How can I find the number of connections currently active in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I intend to write a script to alert me when the number of connections active in my PostgreSQL server exceeds a certain threshold. Where can I find this number in a form I can use for comparison in a script?

My PostgreSQL version is 8.4.8, and my operating system is Debian Squeeze.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you get the active users connected to a postgreSQL database via SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464623/how-can-you-get-the-active-users-connected-to-a-postgresql-database-via-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity view. Each row is a connection.

Comment: Thanks. With this information and some help from #postgres on freenode, I have arrived at the following solution: `psql -Atc 'SELECT count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity'`