# How to list active connections on PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-connection, listings

Is there a command in PostgreSQL to select active connections to a given database?

`psql` states that I can't drop one of my databases because there are **active connections to it**, so I would like to see what the connections are (and from which machines)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you get the active users connected to a postgreSQL database via SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464623/how-can-you-get-the-active-users-connected-to-a-postgresql-database-via-sql)

Comment: Great! i search (badly) and don't found anything.

Can i do something to close others idle connection?

Answer (score 742, accepted):

Oh, I just found that command on PostgreSQL forum:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

Comment: If you would like to limit it to just one database, you can use _SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = 'dbname';_

Comment: How can i get the active database connection from the specific backed service?

Comment: And how about after running `pg_terminate_backend` and my app is still able to run query against the db but I could not see the new connections in pg_Stat_activity?

Comment: if you want to make the output more human readable, run ``\x on;`` first.

Comment: Short n' sweet & focused on remotes:
SELECT datname,usename,application_name,client_addr FROM pg_stat_activity;

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM pg_stat_activity;` for getting just the number of connections.

Answer (score 101):

Following will give you active connections/ queries in postgres DB-

```
SELECT 
    pid
    ,datname
    ,usename
    ,application_name
    ,client_hostname
    ,client_port
    ,backend_start
    ,query_start
    ,query
    ,state
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE state = 'active';
```

You may use 'idle' instead of active to get already executed connections/queries.

Comment: Does idle means connection is active?. If I m releasing connection, still will it be listed as idle?

Comment: Yes @ShivamKubde but as 'idle', and the query above only show 'active' connections, so remove the `WHERE ...` clause and to be able to see what connections are active or idle add the column `state` to the `SELECT` clause

Comment: @ReneChan it is due to too many connections to your database. Normally the maximum is 100. You must have created more than that.

Answer (score 49):

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = 'dbname' and state = 'active';
```

Since `pg_stat_activity` contains connection statistics of all databases having any state, either `idle` or `active`, database name and connection state should be included in the query to get the desired output.

Answer (score 16):

You can check connection details in Postgres using pg_stat_activity. You can apply filter to satisfy your condition. Below are queries.
References: https://orahow.com/check-active-connections-in-postgresql/

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state = 'active';
```

```
select * from pg_stat_activity where state = 'active' and datname = 'REPLACE_DB_NAME_HERE';
```

Answer (score 13):

If you would like to use PgAdmin (for me it is more than convenient), you could do these simple steps. Glad if this is helps

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

[image: example]