# Flask-SQLAlchemy doesn't create table

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to use PostgreSQL with Flask-SQLAlchemy. I made a database named `data_collector` using pgAdmin4. When I try to create a table it's not getting created. I think the connection to the database is not getting established.

I am trying to run it from cmd as:

```
from app import db
db.create_all()
```

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app=Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:postgresql@localhost/data_collector'

db=SQLAlchemy(app)

class Data(db.Model):
    __tablename__="data"
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    email_=db.Column(db.String(120),unique=True)
    height_=db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self,email_,height_):
        self.email_=email_
        self.height_=height_

db.create_all()
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't commit to the database after creating the tables.
You can do that by:

```py
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
    db.session.commit()
```

Do something like this.

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# ---snip---

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
    db.session.commit()    # <- Here commit changes to database


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

This should solve your problem.

If you want to reset(delete) your database then:

```py
with app.app_context():
    db.drop_all()
    db.session.commit()
```

Nothing is written or deleted or updated in database unless you commit using
`db.session.commit()`

If you want to revert the changes before comitting use:
`db.session.rollback()`

Comment: I included                                                                                                                     with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
    db.session.commit()                                                                                                     above  class data, its still not working

Comment: Put that after creating all Classes.

Comment: Thank you but still not working.Can you suggest how to check whether the connection is established or not.

Comment: If connection fails then it will throw an error. Try with a `sqlite` database to see if the tables are created or not.

Comment: Failed connection will throw an error. But try this query `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;` from ->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435839/how-to-select-list-of-active-connections-to-a-postgresql-database   . Also make sure that you installed a database driver like `psychopg2`.

Comment: Works fine with sqlite but I have to use postgres.Can you help?

Comment: Install psycopg2 by `pip3 install psycopg2` if you haven't as SQLAlchemy uses it by default and check your database permissions for the specific user and try to run the above query for checking connections.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution after alot of Googling.

You must import all the `models` before calling `db.create_all()` function like this,

```
def create_db():

from src import models

db.create_all()
db.session.commit()
```

I have all my models in single file but if you have different files, make sure to import them all.