how to know the details of the connections in AWS RDS?
In the current activity section of the AWS RDS i am noticing the number of connections. But i need more information of the connection (where is it from etc).
I am expecting any suggestions which i could go for inorder to find details of the connections(ip from where the connections are from etc.)

AWS doesn't expose that data via the Web UI or the API. You would need to connect to the Postgres database and do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435839/how-to-list-active-connections-on-postgresql

AWS RDS doesn't provide granular details about the source IP addresses of incoming connections directly within the console.
However you could try few indirect methods like -
Enable VPC Flow Logs: If you have Configured VPC Flow Logs for the VPC where your RDS instance resides,This will capture information about network traffic, including source and destination IP addresses, port numbers, and protocol.
Check Ingress rules : Ingress rules of the security group associated with your RDS instance  will reveal the IP address ranges that are allowed to connect to the database.
Also check the AWS CloudWatch Logs Insights.

FYI the question is off-topic and not something to answer (you're also not answering any specific question; you're posting general suggestions)
